# Issues with git pushing to dreamhost server via ssh

Tags: git

I've followed this set of instructions to get set up to be able to push my local branch to my dreamhost server via ssh rather than uploading files via FTP.

[Pushing your local git repository to a DreamHost server — Windows](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000732471-Pushing-your-local-git-repository-to-your-DreamHost-server-Windows)

[Using Git for web development](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000684492-Using-Git-for-web-development)

I have 2 different domains, test and "client sandbox". I can successfully push changes via SSH to the test environment, but cannot to the client sandbox environment. the only difference I can see in the below screenshot is the HEAD branch.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and can't seem to get it. Any help getting pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

If I make a noticeable change to a file and then push, it seems like it works, but the changes aren't reflected in the browser:

[image]

I've done the following:

- verified my .ssh folder exists
- it has the authorized_keys file in it.
- i've given chmod permissions to that directory.
- i've created the post-receive file with the following code in it:

  `#!/bin/sh -l #!/bin/sh`

  `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/user/client-sandbox.mydomain.com git checkout -f
   client_sandbox`

which matches the same set up on my test domain.

Is there a way to set up the sandbox to have another branch as the head rather than master? Maybe that would solve my problem as I'm not pushing to the master branch. Or maybe I should just push to the master branch. Was hoping to keep things consistent across environments.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup should work.

So make sure the `post-receive` hook is executed (and is executable, in the `xxx.git/hooks` folder of the bare repo you are pushing to).
Add an `echo "test"` after the `#!/bin/sh` first line, in order to see, when pushing, if the remote send back at least that echo output.

Comment: I didn't get anything echo'd back. I'm assuming it would show up in the git bash window...got the same response as before. It looks like it's successful, but no changes reflected.